# Как написать свой GC или изменить существующий?

Tags: java, c++, сборщик-мусора

Мне надо организовать свою логику по сборке мусора в Java. В интернете есть [статьи](https://shipilev.net/jvm/diy-gc/) как написать написать свой `GC` и даже видеоролики. Но во всех примерах люди просто переходят к `С++` коду и начинаю показывать примеры. Мне непонятно как подключить себе библиотки с уже существующими `GC`, какие методы уже существуют и как мне подключить свой `GC` к моему `Java` процессу при старте.

Comment: а при чем тут с++?

Comment: @goldstar_labs видать потому, что сборщики HotSpot пишут на C++

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да. Потому что большинство JVM на С++ пишутся

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не существует никаких библиотек с GC. Чтобы написать свой GC, надо изменить код JVM, а потом собрать её.

Answer (score 0):

С llvm можно использовать свой GC 
https://llvm.org/docs/GarbageCollection.html